# MySQL Workbench vs PHP not performing with identical results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following MySQL statements in PHP that yield wildly different and unexpected results from entering them directly in MySQLWorkBench:

```sql
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
SET @idx = 1;
UPDATE Database.Table SET sequence = 9999 WHERE category = 'MyCat' AND sequence = 15;
UPDATE Database.Table SET sequence = @idx := @idx + 1 WHERE category = 'MyCat' AND sequence >= 1 AND sequence <= 15 ORDER BY sequence;
UPDATE Database.Table SET sequence = 1 WHERE category = 'MyCat' AND sequence = 9999;
SELECT * FROM Database.Table WHERE category = 'MyCat';
```

It works as expected in MySQLWorkbench, but is totally weird in PHP. For one, the record at sequence = 15 doesn't move at all, and another unrelated sequence number may or may not in its stead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you execute this as many separate queries from PHP or as single multi statement query?
If the first one, you session variable `@idx` will not work.

In any case, why you are doing it this way?
What wrong with simple query like this:

```sql
UPDATE
    Database.Table
SET
    sequence = IF(sequence = 15, 1, sequence + 1)
WHERE
    category = 'MyCat'
    AND sequence BETWEEN 1 AND 15
;
```

Comment: I am executing as individual statements. I tried what you suggested, but I get the same unreliable results. Sequence 15 doesn't replace sequence 1, and the remaining sequences aren't in their expected order.

Comment: This is strange, it works in [my implementation](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=199551fb4cbe0352087fc0d7a9c0782e) (and locally as well)

Comment: It doesn''t work in Workbench or PHP. I wind up with the sequence 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18...

Comment: I cannot think of any reason why the code might not work. It is very simple query. Have you tried to check my code in your system "as is"? What is your MySQL version? (I've checked in on MySQL 5.7 and MariaDB 10.1)